# Tagging for blogs?

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a simple way to add the ability to add 'tags' to blog entries in Drupal?

Maybe I need to add a module for this functionality?

Comment: Have you tried to do with taxonomy module ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below instruction to enable tags on blogs.

1. Login using admin credentials.
2. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/blog/fields
3. Add Tags field by selecting "Select a Type Fields" as "Term Reference" and widget type as "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)"
4. Click on Save.
5. Select Vocabulary as Tags which comes with Drupal Core in next screen.
6. Click on Save Field Settings.
7. Click on Save Settings in next screen.

That's it !